# MS Word how to wrap a cell around two cells

Tags: microsoft-word

I know that my question is weird but here is the problem.

I'm trying to create a table in MS Word using this schema

[image]

I can split the third column to column 1 and column 2, but I also want to wrap them inside one column that you can think of as the parent column.

For example column 3 would be "result" and has "positive result" and "negative result".

How can I achieve this in MS Word ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Set your table up like this:

[image]

Select the *Column 3* cell and the one to the right of it, go to the *Layout* tab in *Table Tools* and and select *Merge Cells*.

[image]

If the first and second headers don't need a sub header, just merge the header cell with the one directly below it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you want to "wrap them inside one column that you can think of as the parent column," I get the feeling that you're trying to create a nested table, meaning a table within a cell. You do that simply by creating your table, then placing the cursor in the cell where you want the nested table to be, and then creating another table there, exactly as if you were creating an ordinary table (i.e., Table>Insert>Table…)

[image]